# Firebase Storage: .putFile() is delaying in my Flutter/Dart code

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I hope you are all good,

I am using the .putFile() of Firebase Storage,
it does its work, it saves the File (image) in the Storage but, then it NEVER resolves. So, it Doesn't go to the next line. The next line is never executed.

What should I do?

**UPDATE**

Hi everyone I just delayed the function where uploadImageToFirebase() was called. And it worked, because it gave it enough time to do its job.

Thank you for all your responses!

```
Future<String> uploadImageToFirebase(File image) async {
     if (image == null) { return ""; }

     final Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

     final Reference referenceOfUsersImages =
        firebaseStorageRef.child('profilePictures');

     String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

     final Reference referenceOfUserImage =
        referenceOfUsersImages.child(uniqueFileName);

    try {
      referenceOfUserImage.putFile(image);

      String url = await referenceOfUserImage.getDownloadURL();

      return url;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to `await referenceOfUserImage.putFile(image);` so that the upload is finished before you try to get its download URL.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, Frank. Thank you for your response. Now, i added the 'await' keyword, but it still lags, and doesn't go to the next line...

Answer (score 0):

My Code is Working Fine in My App. Please check and Implement in your app. Hope so it's also Helpful for you

```
void uploadChatImage(String value) async {
if (await Utils.hasNetwork()) {
  Utils.showLoader();
  File image = File(value);
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference ref = storage
      .ref()
      .child("${SharedPreferenceHelper().getUserId()}")
      .child(remoteUserId)
      .child("${getRandomString(10)}.jpeg");
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
  uploadTask.then((res) {
    if (res.state == TaskState.success) {
      res.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) {
       print (url);
      }).catchError((onError) {
        print("Got Error $onError");
      });
    }
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use the class UploadTask, I need to use TaskSnapshot instead. But then I dont get the .then() function...